# how can i can i change Html input type week language?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

do you have any idea of how I can display it in french instead of default English?

my code is: `<input  matInput type="week" min="2020-W0">`

Comment: Exaclty what is it that you want to display in french?

Comment: I think you are talking about the internalization of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date Pipe

More Informations:

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe